# Can't insert AI CS6 files as objects into ArcMap 10.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, illustrator

In the past I have inserted Adobe Illustrator files into ArcMap as objects. My old version of AI was 8.0 and ArcMap was 9.2. Now I have arcmap 10.1 and AI CS6. When the process doesn't shut down arcmap, it gives the message.."failed to create object. Make sure object is entered in system registry.
???????

Comment: you need to export your AI CS6 to v8. After Adobe Illustrator v8 they encrypted the .ai file format. v8 ai files can be open in notepad (notepadd++ recommended).

Comment: @Mapperz is right that the file format has been closed since v8; however, this problem is file-format _independent_ and occurs if Illustrator is to be launched for OLE embedding. It is reproducible even if files had been saved as v8 ai file.

Comment: The problem is not limited to ArcGIS. Try to reproduce the error in other 32bit vs in 64bit software (e.g. use *"Insert Object"* in Wordpad). It seems like a OLE configuration issue. There is a similar issue discussed at the [Adobe Forum](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1280573) - maybe it is related to a mixture of 32bit and 64bit applications, or some OLE registry values not set correctly. Are you using a 64bit OS? Are you using 64bit AI? Sometimes, OLE problems can be solved by registry hacking (HKCR section) via manipulating keys in the ClassID entries.

Comment: Wow. didn't even know that was an option. I figured if they could not figure out excel and word anything more graphically complex would have been out of the question.   Did transparencies, shadows and effects came over correctly and rendered correctly when placed over a map and exported?  As a workaround you could try saving AI as EMF and adding as graphic. Static and forget effects such as shadows, opacity but 100% transparency works.